# The dual of a dual basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove the following:

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $k$, and let $V^\star = {\rm Hom}_k(V,k)$ be its dual space. Given a basis $B^\star =(\varphi_1,...,\varphi_n)$ of $V^\star$, there exists a basis $B = (b_1, \dots, b_n)$ of $V$ such that $\varphi_i(b_j) = \delta_{ij}$ for all $i$ and $j$.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint:  Think about the process of using Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization to find an orthonormal basis for $V$, and adapt it.

Comment: An alternative approach is to view the $\varphi_i$'s as row vectors and the $b_j$'s as column vectors. Then construct square matrices $\Phi = [\varphi_1 \dots \varphi_n]^T$ and $B = [b_1 \dots b_n]$. Your condition $\varphi_i(b_j) = \delta_{ij}$ is equivalent to saying that $\Phi B = I$. So you need to argue that $\Phi$ is invertible...